# What will be the approximate downtime for indexing a column in psql

Tags: postgresql

I have an Elixir application that uses Postgres Db and I want to index a field with a row count of 54K. There are few NULL values as well.

I use Ecto.Migration

```
def change do
   create(index(:rules_engine_test_cases, [:rule_set_version_id]))
end
```

Will there be any downtime in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create indexes concurrently to prevent locks.

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY sales_quantity_index ON sales_table (quantity);
```

[Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html)